# JQUERY UI Dialog Box Success Function Is Not Working...Executing But Not Working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to convert the ugly dialog confirmation box to the JQUERY UI.....The confirmation box works.....when I convert it over to the dialogue....it's working....in that I am getting a dialog box...but the success function itself is no longer working....It's executing...it shows my console log message...But it's not actually executing and I'm a bit lost as to why not...maybe a $this issue?

This is working....The original confirm( Are you Sure you want to )....

```
row.find('a.' + delCssSelector).click(function() {

  var result = confirm("Are you sure you want to Delete?");
  if (result) {
    var row = $(this).parents('.dynamic-form');
    var itemIdInput = row.find('input:hidden[id $= "-id"]');
    var itemId = itemIdInput.val();
    var deleteInput = `<input type="hidden" name="research_line_items_to_delete" value="${itemId}">`; // Update here....
    if ($(deleteInput).val()) {
      $('#research_line_items_to_delete').append(deleteInput); // Update here....
    }

    var row = $(this).parents('.' + options.formCssClass),
      del = row.find('input:hidden[id $= "-DELETE"]'),
      buttonRow = row.siblings("a." + addCssSelector + ', .' + options.formCssClass + '-add'),
      forms;
    if (del.length) {
      del.val('on');
      row.hide();
      forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass);
      totalForms.val(forms.length);
    } else {
      row.remove();
      forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass).not('.formset-custom-template');
      totalForms.val(forms.length);
    }
    for (var i = 0, formCount = forms.length; i < formCount; i++) {
      applyExtraClasses(forms.eq(i), i);
      if (!del.length) {
        forms.eq(i).find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
          updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, i);
        });
      }
    }

    if (!showDeleteLinks()) {
      $('a.' + delCssSelector).each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
      });
    }
    if (buttonRow.is(':hidden') && showAddButton()) buttonRow.show();
    if (options.removed) options.removed(row);
    return false;
  }
});
};
```

I've got this "working" too...but it doesn't actually execute...I've made sure the logic is identical and it does in fact execute and show me the console.log message...but it's not actually executing...

```
row.find('a.' + delCssSelector).click(function() {

  var target = $(this).attr("href");
  var content = $(this).attr("title");
  var title = $(this).attr("alt");

  $("#dialog").dialog({
    draggable: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    width: 'auto',
    title: title,
    buttons: {
      'Yes': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        callback(true);
      },
      'No': function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        callback(false);
      }
    }
  });

  function callback(value) {
    if (value) {
      var row = $(this).parents('.dynamic-form');
      var itemIdInput = row.find('input:hidden[id $= "-id"]');
      var itemId = itemIdInput.val();
      var deleteInput = `<input type="hidden" name="research_line_items_to_delete" value="${itemId}">`; // Update here....
      console.log("hereyo");
      if ($(deleteInput).val()) {
        $('#research_line_items_to_delete').append(deleteInput); // Update here....
      }
      console.log($(deleteInput).val());
      var row = $(this).parents('.' + options.formCssClass),
        del = row.find('input:hidden[id $= "-DELETE"]'),
        buttonRow = row.siblings("a." + addCssSelector + ', .' + options.formCssClass + '-add'),
        forms;
      if (del.length) {
        del.val('on');
        row.hide();
        forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass);
        totalForms.val(forms.length);
      } else {
        row.remove();
        forms = $('.' + options.formCssClass).not('.formset-custom-template');
        totalForms.val(forms.length);
      }
      for (var i = 0, formCount = forms.length; i < formCount; i++) {
        applyExtraClasses(forms.eq(i), i);
        if (!del.length) {
          forms.eq(i).find(childElementSelector).each(function() {
            updateElementIndex($(this), options.prefix, i);
          });
        }
      }

      if (!showDeleteLinks()) {
        $('a.' + delCssSelector).each(function() {
          $(this).hide();
        });
      }
      if (buttonRow.is(':hidden') && showAddButton()) buttonRow.show();
      if (options.removed) options.removed(row);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
};
```

The associated HTML...

```
  <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the &apos;x&apos; icon.</p>
  </div>
```

Any thoughts on what is missing are greatly appreciated....

Comment: You shouldn't call `$("#dialog").dialog()` in a loop. Each time you call it, you re-initialize the dialog widget, replacing the old settings. You won't get a different dialog for each row.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the feedback.  I'm essentially calling the dialog when the user clicks on .a It works perfectly fine with the confirm approach...I can't seem to replicate the functionality with the dialog() approach.  Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: To open the dialog you use `$("#dialog").dialog("open")`. You only have to initialize it once, you use other methods to open and close it when needed.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the feedback.  I tried moving the initialization around but it didn't seem to help.  My code as documented is working and it's actually executing the true loop....but the code that actually deletes the line isn't working.  I've moved the code around quite a bit and the closest I've gotten it to work is the code as documented above.

Comment: In your `callback()`, you have an ambiguous `this` reference: `var row = $(this).parents('.dynamic-form');` Since this is wrapped inside a function and it is defined inside a function, there may be some confusion.  I would advise defining the `row` before the callback.

Comment: @Twisty  Thanks for the feedback.  I had someone help me the other day and determined that because I'm looping through rows and incorporating a modal, I need to find a way to pass the ID into my script above.  The code above works on a singular basis...but once I incorporate a modal...then I need to add more code.  Thanks for taking the time to provide feedback.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following lightweight example.

```js
$(function() {
  function makeDialog(row, title, trueCall) {
    if (title == undefined) {
      title = "Delete Row " + row.data("id");
    }
    if (trueCall == undefined) {
      trueCall = function() {
        row.remove();
      };
    }

    var d = $("<div>").html("Please confirm that you want to delete this row.").dialog({
      draggable: false,
      modal: true,
      resizable: false,
      width: 'auto',
      title: title,
      buttons: {
        'Yes': function() {
          trueCall();
          d.dialog("close").dialog("destroy").remove();
        },
        'No': function() {
          d.dialog("close").dialog("destroy").remove();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $(".delete-row").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    makeDialog($(this).closest("tr"));
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr data-id="001">
    <td>Item 1</td>
    <td><a href="" class="delete-row">X</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="002">
    <td>Item 2</td>
    <td><a href="" class="delete-row">X</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr data-id="003">
    <td>Item 3</td>
    <td><a href="" class="delete-row">X</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This gives you a more specific reference.

Comment: Thank you so much for this example.  Will help me immensely.  Thanks again.